# Inserting 2M nodes/relationship into Neo4J in a single transaction never succeeds

Tags: c#, docker, neo4j, .net-core, cypher

I have been playing around with neo4j/cypher recently to store objects into it.
I am using netcore with neo4j.Driver v1.5.

Everything was fine until I needed more performance because I am going to need to store at runtime millions of nodes/relationships.

After spending some time digging around some other questions and article, I decided to refactor what I had as I was making calls to neo4j the "naive" way. (1 request per create)

I am now using query parameters the following way to reduce the number of queries:

For node creation

```
MERGE (model:EngineeringModel {id: $engineeringModelId})
WITH model
UNWIND $nodes AS node
CREATE (thing:Label1:Label2:LabelN)<-[:Model]-(model)
SET thing = node
```

where $engineeringModelId is a string and $nodes an array of objects that correspond to the properties of each node.

For Relationship creation

```
MATCH (model:EngineeringModel {id: $engineeringModelId}) USING INDEX 
model:EngineeringModel(id) 
UNWIND $relationships AS relationship 
MATCH (s:Label1 {id: relationship.source}) USING INDEX s:Label1(id) 
UNWIND relationship.sourceRelationships AS sourceRelationship 
UNWIND sourceRelationship.targets AS target 
MATCH (t:IIdentifiable {id: target}) USING INDEX t:IIdentifiable(id) 
CALL apoc.create.relationship(s, sourceRelationship.type, {{}}, t) YIELD rel 
RETURN rel
```

where,
$engineeringModelId is a string,
$relationships is an array of objects that contain a source node and all its target/relationship-type.

I managed to save about 1M nodes/relationships within 5 minutes with Transaction Functions and splitting the requests to up to 20000 objects. (The splitting is done in the C# code)

```
using (var session = Driver.Session())
{
    session.WriteTransaction(tx => tx.Run(request, params));
}
```

The issue with this is that it is not "transaction safe" in the sense where a commit will be executed for every 20000 nodes/relationships.

By using Explicit transaction as described in 4.3.2.3 [neo4j docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/sessions-transactions/)
I haven't been able to perform the commit within a reasonable amount of time (I never managed to save).

```
this.driverLifeCycle.BeginTransaction(); // connect and start a new transaction
this.DriverLifeCycle.Transaction.Run(cqlQuery.ToString(), parameters); xN times
this.driverLifeCycle.CommitTransaction(); // commit the transaction
```

Here are the config I have for my docker container:

```
NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=2G 
NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_maxSize=2G 
NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_initial__size=2G
```

Would anyone know how to make this explicit transaction to work correctly?

Thank you all very much for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some investigation and with some input from the neo4j community on neo4j-slack, it seems it is not possible to achieve what I want directly in my version of neo4j (v 3.2.5) with driver v1.5 for .netcore and a workaround to "manually" handle the transaction is required.

The workaround is basically the following:

- Add an extra **TMP** label for all nodes to create in the current transaction with a **transactionId** property that is generated upon a POST request,
- Add an extra property **transactionId** on relationships created during the transaction using the same transaction id.

I am also commiting every few thousands (10k in my case) nodes/relationships so that neo4j can deal with it and make sure that these extra labels and properties are included.

At the end of the operation:

- on success, I remove the extra label and properties applied on nodes and relationships

  ```
  MATCH (tmpNode:TMP { transactionId: $transactionId })
  USING INDEX tmpNode:TMP(transactionId)
  REMOVE tmpNode:TMP
  REMOVE tmpNode.transactionId

  MATCH ()-[r { transactionId: $transactionId }]->()
  REMOVE r.transactionId
  ```
- if a problem occured, I delete all the nodes and relationships that were created.

  ```
  MATCH (tmpNode:TMP { transactionId: $transactionId })
  USING INDEX tmpNode:TMP(transactionId)
  DETACH DELETE tmpNode

  MATCH ()-[tmpRel { transactionId: $transactionId }]->()
  DELETE tmpRel
  ```

both operations could have been simplified into one request instead of 2 but given the amount of data, doing it this way is more efficient.

On my local machine, I manage to run this in about 10 minutes which is still not great but at least doable.